# The fonts in Android Studio doesn't work

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, fonts

*The fonts* in Android Studio **doesn't work**... 
In XML are looking good but in the emulator and on my phone *the font* **doesn't work**.
Why?

Comment: Can you update your question with the layout.xml code and the font you are trying to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do is access a resource file.
1) In your app, right click res folder < new < Android Resource Directory.
then select Font as resource type, click ok.

2) Click on the design tab, click the TextView you want to change. Then, on left, go to attributes. Scroll to fontFamily, click the drop box and scroll to bottom. That should bring you to a selection of fonts you can "import" into resource folder. All you'd need to is set the XML to access it. (i.e @font/aldrich)